# What's happening when I create a file in a "NTFS compressed" directory?

Tags: ntfs, compression, storage, io

What's exactly happening? The files appear in the UI as compressed. Is it?

If so, is it written twice (like, uncompressed version of the new files is stored, as a buffer, and compressed then (so stored again then) or do the compression apply on the fly (as it inherit of the attribute in first place)?

Comment: Its compressed on the fly.

Comment: http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-compressed.htm

Comment: I didn't even thought to check there.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a new file is created in a folder with the [compressed (C) attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute#DOS_and_Windows) then it'll also inherit that attribute and will be compressed

> A directory's compression attribute provides a default compression attribute for newly created files and subdirectories. When you call [CreateFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createfilea) or [CreateDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya) to create a new file or directory, the new file or directory inherits the compression attribute of its parent directory.
>
> [Compression Attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/compression-attribute)

It'll be compressed on-the-fly without any uncompressed data being saved first

However if you move a non-compressed file from the same partition then it won't be compressed, only its parent is changed from the old folder to the new folder. And if you copy a compressed file from another partition then it'll be decompressed then copied and recompressed upon saving at the destination